C++ UI MFC Do not let Icons Highlight we hovering over "+" or "-" in the Tree Control
enter image description here
Initially the icons did not highlight when we hover over "+" or "-" in the Tree Control.
Later when We have switched from .ico to .png for icons now.
IDI_EVENTREPORT PNG      "res\\Icon_Enable_18x18.png" 

Initializing it to get icons :
    m_pImageList = new CImageList();
    ASSERT(m_pImageList != NULL);
    m_pImageList->Create(18, 18, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 8, 8);// Use ILC_COLOR32 for PNG with alpha

    // Index 0: 有効
    if (m_pngCEIDEnable.loadFromResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_EVENTREPORT))) {
        m_pImageList->Add(m_pngCEIDEnable.createIcon());
    }

And after loading the the .png we icons get highlighted and darker and darker as we hover over "+" or "-" in the Tree Control.
I have tried to use OnCustomDraw.Everything is fails.
void CTreeCEID::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW pNMTVCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

    switch (pNMTVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        break;

    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        {
            // Prevent the icons from being highlighted while keeping the text appearance unchanged
            if (pNMTVCD->nmcd.uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
            {
                // Maintain the text and background as default
                pNMTVCD->clrTextBk = CLR_NONE;
                pNMTVCD->clrText = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT);
            }
            *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        }
        break;
    default:
        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        break;
    }
}


